# How to add a custom wc_add_notice in Admin Pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I try to add a wc notice in an admin page.

```
function some_hook_function() {

 wc_add_notice(__('Done!'), 'notice');

 wp_safe_redirect( wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : admin_url( 'edit.php?post_type=shop_order' ) );

 exit;
}

add_action( 'some_action' , 'some_hook_function', 10);
```

However it doesn't work. I am able to add an admin notice but I don't want to do that. I just need a classical wc notice after a redirection.

Comment: Please follow the documentation ---- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_notices/

Comment: As I said before, I don't need admin notices.

Answer (score 1):

You have to active cookie/session for the customer by following code before calling  wc_add_notice function:

```
if (!WC()->session->has_session()) {
    WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie(true);
}
```

It's necessary for actions such as payment response to your website.

Answer (score 0):

You can't display it on admin pages without calling `wc_print_notices()`.
By default this function will echo all the notice. If however you want to get the notices, pass `true` in the function as `$notices = wc_print_notices(true);`

Comment: can you share an example through my function?

Comment: there are ways... you just have to call `wc_print_notices()` in